# JavaFX ComboBox Crash

Tags: java, javafx, combobox, fatal-error

After using ComboBoxes in an IntelliJ JavaFX application for many months without any crashes or errors, my program now crashes whenever I try to click on a ComboBox.

I decided to do some investigating by creating a new project with just a ComboBox in a TilePane, when I click on it the same thing happens.

Here is the error I get:

[Fatal Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMQyM.png)

Here is the code that produces the error:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Orientation;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.TilePane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage s) {
        int width = 1600;
        int height = 900;
        TilePane r = new TilePane(Orientation.VERTICAL);
        Scene sc = new Scene(r, width, height);
        VBox vbox = new VBox();
        s.setScene(sc);
        s.show();
        ComboBox testBox = new ComboBox();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            testBox.getItems().add(i);
        }
        r.getChildren().add(testBox);
    }
}
```

As far as I can tell, this is how ComboBoxes are supposed to be used, although I may be wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: The code posted does not throw exceptions and should work as it did. You may want to look at the log file listed in the error message.

Answer (score 0):

You need to update DirectX First.

If it doesn't work you need to replace the D3D9.dll in c:\Windows\System32 and run `regsvr32 d3d9.dll`  in CMD